# ¿Cómo enviar un String de una clase a una interfaz en un JFrame en Java?

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8.2

Tengo en una clase la siguiente función:

```
public boolean resultado (String direccion) throws RemoteException{                
    arch_encon = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(direccion);
    return true;
}
```

Me imprime el resultado en consola de NetBeans. 
Pero lo que necesito es ponerlo dentro de un txt, que se llama "txtArchivo" en la interfaz.

Intenté hacer esto:

```
txtArchivo.setText(direccion):
```

Pero no funciona. 
Espero que me puedan ayudar llevo un rato aquí y no encuentro la forma

Comment: Pasa el objeto *txtArchivo* al método **resultado** como parámetro.

Comment: Puedes pasarlo como parámetro o meterlo en una variable static y consultarla